# How to Compare the same Char Value in a Cell Array 1x1 with If Else Sentence

Tags: matlab, if-statement

First i do my connection and assign the names for table, columns, rows...

```
conn = database('db', 'user', 'pass');
```

Then i make a query, for select in the data base an Varchar

```
curs = exec(conn, 'select row/column from table');
```

I request the Data

```
curs = fetch(curs);
AA = curs.Data;
```

then my problem begin... I'll add a variable with the name 'Alex', to find the same name in my database to the assigned column and use the if statement to verify their existence..

```
var = 'Alex';
```

then I wonder what is the best choice to retrieve the data and make a comparison between the database and my Variable:

```
index = find(strcmp(AA,var));
```

or

```
data = strfind(AA,var);
```

and my structure for the if statement is this:

```
if AA == var

  msgbox('Data Exist')

end
```

this doesn't work for me, i just receive "Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'."

Comment: The error message is telling you that the `==` (equality operator) does not exist when at least one of the inputs is a cell, as in this case with `AA`.  If you are expecting all elements in `AA` to be strings (char arrays), then you could just iterate through each element of `AA` and compare with `var`.  Or, one of your other two options will probably work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `AA` is guaranteed to be a 1x1 cell array `strcmp(var, AA{1})` or `isequal({var}, AA)`should work. However, if it can have more elements you can use `ismember(var, AA)`.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm assuming you have something like:

```
var = 'Alex';
AA = {'Alex'};
```

Now, you can handle this in several ways, my favorite being:

```
isequal(var, AA{:})
```

The key point here is the `{:}` that extracts the content of the cell.

`if var == AA{:}` would work too, but only if `var` and `AA{1}` are the same length, otherwise it will cause an error. I would therefore not recommend using `==` for strings.

Comment: IF you do want to use `==` for strings you should think of using `try ...your code...[\n] catch exception [\n] end` THis would keep your code running and only tell you that sth went wrong.